# Ember Data One to One Relationship Record Creation Fails

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I receive the following error when I use Ember Data to create records from a JSON response. What gives? I am following what the docs state.

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Ember Data expected a number or string to represent the record(s) in the `user` relationship instead it found an object. If this is a polymorphic relationship please specify a `type` key. If this is an embedded relationship please include the `DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin` and specify the `user` property in your serializer's attrs object.
```

JSON being parsed:

```
[
    {
        "id": 76,
        "title": "Title",
        "shipped": 0,
        "date": "2015-05-21T05:00:00.000Z",
        "user": {
            "firstName": "First Name",
            "lastName": "Last Name",
            "email": "hellothere@gmail.com",
            "id": 1
        }
    }
]
```

Shipment Model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    user: DS.belongsTo('user', { async: false })    
});
```

Route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

   beforeModel: function() {

        if(!localStorage.accessToken) {
            this.transitionTo('login');
        }

    },

   model: function() {      
      var shipmentObjects = [];
      var App = this;
      Ember.$.getJSON('http://localhost:1337/subscription/1/shipments/upcoming', function(shipments) {
            shipments.forEach(function(data) {
            var shipment = App.store.push('shipment', data);
                shipmentObjects.pushObject(shipment);
            });
      });
      return shipmentObjects;
   }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom serializer, if you can't modify your json response and manage to arrange data in other way

```
App.MODELNAMESerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend({
  extract: function(store, type, payload, id, requestType){
     var shipments = [];

     //CREATE A NEW PAYLOAD THAT EMBER CAN READ

     var _payload = {  };
     return this._super(store, type, _payload, id, requestType);
  }
});
```

Your json should look something like this

```
{
   shipments: [
     {
      "id": 76,
      "title": "Title",
      "shipped": 0,
      "date": "2015-05-21T05:00:00.000Z",
      "user_id": 1,
      }
     ],
      "users": [
      {
        "firstName": "First Name",
        "lastName": "Last Name",
        "email": "hellothere@gmail.com",
        "id": 1
       }
   ]
}
```

Comment: I can modify my JSON but why would I change it to your example? The user object belongs to a shipment and there are many shipments.

Comment: If you separate your json with a shipment array with multiple objects just associated with a user id, and below a user array with all the user info... Ember will handle this as associated models and create every single shipment and user records with ember data. 

Ember expects an id for the relation between your models

Comment: I'll accept this. While I did not format my JSON the same, giving Ember an ID relation in the JSON does work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message. It could hardly be clearer. By default, Ember Data expects an association to be represented by an ID. If the association is instead embedded, you must tell Ember Data that. You'll need something like:

```
// serializers/shipment.js
export default ApplicationSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
    attrs: {
        user: { embedded: 'always' }
    }
});
```

And remove the `{async: false}`, since the data is embedded right there.

See http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html.

Comment: As a sanity check, try adding the above to the application serializer itself. Also, I assume that the JSON array you show is actually inside an object of the form `{ shipments: [ ] }`, right?

Comment: No luck. This has to be something very straight forward.

Comment: Nope, the JSON is as posted. This works as long as I remove any relationships from the model.